# Missing http delegate after compiling and installing 6.9.2-4

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick

I'm running on Ubuntu 14 on AWS EC2, and I was using an older version of ImageMagick (6.7).
I have just downloaded the source, compiled and installed version 6.9.2-4 - I have followed the exact directions from here:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php
However, I cannot do any operation with images from the web - for example:

```
convert  "http://www.nike.com/nikebasketball/us/en_US/images/kicks/athletes/kobe_bryant.png" test.png
convert: unable to open image `//www.nike.com/nikebasketball/us/en_US/images/kicks/athletes/kobe_bryant.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `HTTP' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined `test.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3230.
```

The tests were successfull, and my version info says:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-4 Q16 x86_64 2015-10-27 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff x zlib
```

If I run:

```
convert -list delegate | grep http
```

I get:

```
https =>          "curl" -s -k -L -o "%o" "https:%M"
```

If I reinstall the 6.7 version, it works fine...

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps anyone, I was finally able to solve this by following the instructions provided here:
https://www.namhuy.net/1730/install-imagemagick-6-8-linux-mint-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install `html2ps` utility. I would assume `html2ps` is apart of the [postscript](/questions/tagged/postscript) package.

```
convert -list delegate | grep html
    htm =>          "html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"
   html =>          "html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"
  shtml =>          "html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried it, but it doesn't work... I get the same result as you have put above for the 'convert -list delegate | grep html', but still get the same error when trying to run any command on an image from the web.

Answer (score 0):

Open `policy.xml` (Usually located in `/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6`) and uncomment out the following line:

```
<!-- 
  <delegate decode="https" command="&quot;curl&quot; -s -k -L -o &quot;%o&quot; &quot;https:%F&quot;"/>
-->
```

This will allow ImageMagick to use the `https` decoder (which is just a `curl` call)